# How to join MySQL 3 tables to filter correct resualt

Tags: mysql

I wrote mysql for filter resualt there are 3 tables

```
SELECT 
    rb_function_booking_events.event_title, 
    rb_function_booking_events.event_id, 
    rb_function_category.category_name,
    rb_function_category.category_colour, 
    rb_function_rooms.colour as fc_colour 
FROM 
    rb_function_booking_events 
    JOIN rb_function_category 
        ON rb_function_booking_events.category = rb_function_booking_events.category 
    JOIN rb_function_rooms 
        ON rb_function_rooms.room_id = rb_function_booking_events.fc_id 
WHERE 
    rb_function_booking_events.booking_date='1396310400' 
    AND rb_function_booking_events.fc_id='1'
```

- rb_function_booking_events table has 1 row
- rb_function_category table has 3 rows
- rb_function_rooms table has 6 rows

I want to filter rb_function_booking_events row but when this query execute I got 3 results instead of 1 result, some one please help

Comment: add a group by at the end `group by rb_function_booking_events.event_id`

Comment: DISTINCT is appropriate for this purpose. If using GROUP BY, then you need to be thinking more carefully about which rows you actually want returned.

Comment: Both are wrong or right depending on the real question behind the query. The question right now is wrong in itself.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have for one booking_event multiple categories or multiple rooms, you have to decide what to do with them. Look at the result rows and ask yourself what colour you want to see.

You could just concat them with `group_concat(distinct category_name)`, in that case the hint with `group by` is correct. You could try to see just multiple rows if the results differ, in that case just use `select distinct`.

But the question "which single room is booked this afternoon" is just invalid if there are many rooms booked.